# Spring Security, sign out of multiple applications at once

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout, cas

I have three separate applications that are all secured with spring security. When a user logs out of the main application, I need to also make sure they're logged out of the api application and a social widget application as well. Right now, I've set the logout success url of the primary application to the logout url of the second, and so on. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, how do your users log in to your applications? Is there some single sign-on solution in place? If so, this solution should also address single sign-out.

Your question is tagged with CAS: CAS not only supports Single Sign-On, but also [Single-Sign Out](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/single+sign+out).

Comment: yes, we are using CAS. From my reading of the single sign out cas documentation, there were two things that stood out as potential deal breakers with that solution. One, while the single sign out would destroy the ticket, the cookie on the client was still there, and the documentation seemed to imply that that meant if that user then hit that application, they actually would still have a local session with that app. Two, it stated that the single sign out service would make a POST request to every single service in the registry upon sign out. We have almost 100 services all using cas, this....

Comment: If you do have 100 services and a user with a session in each of these, can you think of any other way to terminate the sessions, other than a logout request to each service? A shared session cache is the only thing that comes to my mind...

Comment: well, here's something I thought of today, the three applications that I'm dealing with are all deployed under the same domain, just on different subdomains. so if i could set the JSESSIONID cookie domain to be .mydomain.com in all the applications, then theoretically the first application would have privileges to remove all the JSESSIONIDs and would of course also log them out of the cas, so on any subsequent requests, they would automatically be redirected back to a sign in. could this work?